# TinyMCE editor when embedded in React with Redux Architecture, fails to update React DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, tinymce, react-dom

TinyMCE when embedded in React with Redux Architecture, fails to update React DOM when props are passed when data is updated via redux flow.

> Code Reference: [click here for reference to code](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-vzpe8)

Process of Implementation:-

- In Reducer file we have an initial state of content, which is used to render data

```
const initialState = {
  value: 0,
};
```

- Via Redux flow on click of button triggered via TinyMCE actions, therein we dispatch an action which in return increment the value, but it doesn't get updated on DOM.

Review how TinyMCE can update the DOM while updating the data using Props data. You can take reference from codesandbox code link https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-vzpe8.

***Note:- Please close warning console window as it appears in development in codesandbox***

As per updates I have used React Library for TInyMCE, where in I am not able to have update or Did Mount stage call via ReactDom Server rendering URL for code reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-spence-tmz0x

Comment: Nobody will fork and locally try your code. Provide a codesandbox (or similar) working example instead

Comment: Based on your suggestion I have uploaded on codesandbox with link https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-vzpe8

Comment: Using Tiny with these kind of component-based frameworks generally is easier when using a "wrapper". Tiny's Official React wrapper is here: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react

Comment: Thanks, Tiny Lincoln. Soon will share with you the issue we facing in React Wrapper wherein we are not able to bind multiple components into tiny react wrapper, as react wrapper takes data as a string. will share another POC with you shortly with tiny react wrapper.

Comment: @TinyLincoln for the reference I am sharing the code link https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-spence-tmz0x wherein passing component to rendertoString do not calls the update or did mount lifecycle after first render, I want to make it statefull component using react tiny libraray.

Comment: @keul I have updated the post by adding the reference to working code, please review

Comment: @TinyLincoln have you reviewed the TinyMCE via React library wherein we are not able to achieve the statefulness of the component, as in Tinymce editor instance the data is passed as a string. please review https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-spence-tmz0x

Comment: @Keul did you got the time to review the issue related to TinyMCE?

Comment: @AnkitA I never used TinyMCE integration for react, but it seems you are trying to have the component as a controlled ones (because you want to pilot the editor content), so documentation explicitly refer to this: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#usingthetinymcereactcomponentasacontrolledcomponent

Comment: @Keul Thanks for your input. But TinyMCE documentation https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#usingthetinymcereactcomponentasacontrolledcomponent doesn't clearly explain when we need to bind multiple components into it. For the reference I have also had POC based on it which doesn't hold the staefullness of the component, refer https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-spence-tmz0x